# Constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for tableview cell's content view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

This warning is driving me crazy:

> [Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints
>   ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content
>   view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard
>   height instead.

I have a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell. The table view cell has auto row height, and the collection view has cell size of 44x44. The collection view cell has default size. I have a button inside the collection view cell with constraints pinning it to the top, bottom, left, and right of the cell (I also tried manually setting its size to 44x44). You can see the rest of the constraints in the following image:

[image: Storyboard Constraints]

When I try to set the Table View Cell Row Height as custom equal to 44, I get an error that the constraints are conflicting and one of them needs to be removed. When I set it to 50, I get the warning above again.

Any ideas? :S

Thanks!

Comment: You have set collectionView's top and centre. It's weird inside table view cell. you should set top and bottom of collection view inside cell.

Comment: @PaulMarshal still same warning. The center was actually set by xcode using the add missing constraints option - I had top and bottom before but hoped the auto add constraints would fix the warning but it didn't :( i also tried center and height. Still same warning.

Comment: This warning mainly arrived with table view and collection view cell even you are using custom cell XIB. You need to just checkout what is actual size you cell and which constrains you missed. i.e. Cell height is 50, CollectionVIew's Top and Bottom are 5, Then height should be set to 40. So It will not showing error.

Comment: @PaulMarshal double checked, everything looks fine, still not working :( Collection View's Cell Size is 44 height, icon cell is 44 height, the View inside the table cell that houses the Collection View is set automatically (I see it at 43.5), and the Table View Cell's Row Height is set to custom and 44 (tried setting it to auto also, but same error).

Comment: If possible, then Can you please share your demo with me ?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Upload your demo in dropbox and share url in comment.

Answer (score 1):

make sure in your cell class to define constraints in a such way that cell contentView will have a least 1px height/width (e.g. height constraint >= 1)

I do like this (collectionView is a subview of cells contentView)

```
collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 1).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

CollectionView constraints are wrong, you added top constraint and also aligning collectionView center vertically, remove one of them. also take a look of screen short.[image]

Comment: tried removing the top constraint, removing the vertical center constraint and keeping the top, and adding both a top and a bottom. Still getting the same warning.

Comment: should mention that when I removed the top, I added a height as well of 44 and that didn't fix the issue either. still getting the warning.

Comment: I got that same error. Apparently, the reason was that cell height was 22 in TableViewCel, smaller than tableView Row Height of  25.